# constructing a TensorFlow tensor that behaves as empty when passed to tf.concat()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am constructing a computation graph with topology that varies based on some hyperparameters. At some point, a concatenation takes place:

```
c = tf.concat([a, b], axis=-1)
```

The tensor `a` has shape `(None, m)`.
The tensor `b` has shape `(None, n)` where `n` depends on the hyperparameters. For one value of the hyperparameters, the tensor `b` should be conceptually **empty**, e.g. we want `c` and `a` to be the same.

I can build the graph successfully with the following:

```
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 0), name="Empty")
```

but then, if I run a session, TensorFlow raises an `InvalidArgumentError` stating:

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Empty' with dtype float and shape [?,0]
```

Is there any way to construct a tensor that will behave as empty in the `concat` operation, but does not require feeding a spurious input?

Obviously, I'm aware that I could just add a special case, wrapper, etc. in the code where I construct the graph. I'm hoping to avoid that.

Full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 10))
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 0), name="Empty")
c = tf.concat([a, b], axis=-1)
assert c.shape.as_list() == [None, 10]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a_feed = np.zeros((100, 10))
    c = sess.run(c, {a : a_feed})
```

Comment: why not pass a meanless numpy to b when it is empty

Comment: because the consumer of this code shouldn't need to know about this weird empty placeholder whose only purpose is to make `concat` work in a special case.

Answer (score 1):

If you were not to use `tf.placeholder()` to feed your data, but `tf.Estimator`, then the solution is trivial, since you could just define:

```
b = tf.zeros([a.shape[0].value, 0])
```

So, in case the shape of a is known,

```
c = tf.concat([a,b],axis=-1)
assert c.shape == a.shape
```

will always succceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.placeholder_with_default](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default) which does not require the placeholder to be fed.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Hparams
batch_size = 100
a_dim = 10
b_dim = 0

# Placeholder for a which is required to be fed.
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, a_dim))

# Placeholder for b, which doesn't have to be fed.
b_default = np.zeros((batch_size, b_dim), dtype=np.float32)
b = tf.placeholder_with_default(
    b_default, (None, b_dim), name="Empty"
)
c = tf.concat([a, b], axis=-1)
assert c.shape.as_list() == [None, a_dim + b_dim]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a_feed = np.zeros((batch_size, a_dim))
    b_feed = np.ones((batch_size, b_dim))
    c_out = sess.run(c, {a : a_feed})
    # You can optionally feed in b:
    # c_out = sess.run(c, {a : a_feed, b : b_feed})
    print(c_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message indicates, you also have to feed b

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a_feed = np.zeros((100, 10))
    b_feed = np.zeros((100, 0)) 
    c = sess.run(c, {a : a_feed, b: b_feed})
```

It passes on my computer.

Comment: In the question I asked: "Is there any way to construct a tensor that will behave as empty in the `concat` operation, but **does not require feeding a spurious input?**" - so I was specifically trying to avoid the solution you describe.