# Concatenating empty array in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

So basically, my question is the same as [Concatenating empty array in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732589/concatenating-empty-array-in-numpy/22732845) but for Tensorflow.

Mainly, the motivation is to handle the initial array in a prettier way that using a if statement. My current pseudo-code is:

```
E = None
for a in A:
    if E is None:
        E = a
    else:
        E = tf.concat([E, a], axis=0)
```

This technique works but I would like to make it a prettier way and maybe using only `tf.Tensor`. This is a code of a custom layer so I am interested in a code that works inside a model.

I would like a solution closer to the accepted response initializing E as: `E = np.array([], dtype=np.int64).reshape(0,5)`.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888829/constructing-a-tensorflow-tensor-that-behaves-as-empty-when-passed-to-tf-concat) gets close enough but when I init E as:

```
E = tf.zeros([a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 0])
...
```

I get an empty tensor as a result with only the correct shape but not filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TF2, you can simply port the numpy solution with TensorFlow functions:

```
>>> xs = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5],[10,20,30,40,50]])
>>> ys = tf.reshape(tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32),(0,5))
>>> ys
<tf.Tensor: shape=(0, 5), dtype=int32, numpy=array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=int32)>
>>> tf.concat([ys,xs], axis=0)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 5), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: I tried to do that and I get: `*** tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [0,1,2,3] vs. shape[1] = [1,1,2,3] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat`.

My E is `<tf.Tensor: shape=(0, 1, 2, 3), dtype=complex64, numpy=array([], shape=(0, 1, 2, 3), dtype=complex64)>` 

and a is `<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 2, 3), dtype=complex64, numpy=
array([[[[0.+0.j, 1.+1.j, 2.+2.j],
         [6.+6.j, 7.+7.j, 8.+8.j]]]], dtype=complex64)>`

Comment: I can't reproduce. Are you sure you are concatenating along the correct `axis`?

Comment: Ups, you were right! I was using another axis! Thanks